# Saving with PrimaryKeyRelatedField django-rest

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm building an endpoint that allows posting to django backend. Deal Model has ManyToMany Relation top book runner, and my serializer by default has PrimaryKeyRelatedField below:

## Models.py

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    book_runner = models.ManyToManyField(BookRunner, blank=True, null=True, related_name="deal_book_runner")
```

## Serializers.py

```
class DealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book_runner = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, many=True, queryset=BookRunner.objects.all(), required=False)
    equity = Equity.objects.create(**equity_data)

def create(self, validated_data):
    deal = Deal.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return deal
```

## Views.py

```
class DealAdminViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Deal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateDealSerializer

    def create(self, request, format=None):
        book_runner = request.data.get('book_runner', None) #array
```

Printing data before validation (validated_data) where the program breaks:

```
{'book_runner': u'2'}
```

Now when I post a deal with book runner with primary key=2, I get an error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <property object at 0x7f1559578158> is not JSON serializable
```

I want to use both array and numbers of primary keys in the future. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is an error concerning the JSON You send to rest framework. It didn't succeed to deserialize it.
Check the JSON format is valid.